Using class non-static member function for callback
This is a bit tricky to describe, so bear with me. I have 2 separate libraries I'm trying to mesh. One library is a numerical optimizer (right now the Nelder Mead optimizer is implemented) and the other is an sensor calibration library. The optimizer library needs the user to specify and pass a pointer to a callback function to "optimize over". The sensor library has a generic sensor class to store calibration data for various sensors (one class for each sensor) and needs to call this optimizer and pass the callback. However, since the callback function is a non-static member of the sensor class, it throws errors like "error: invalid use of non-static member function".
Below is a really dumbed down set of files to serve as a basic example of what I'm trying to do:
optimize.h
#pragma once

double Optimizer(      double  (*func)(const double&),
                 const double& arg)
{
    return func(arg);
}

testLib.h
#pragma once

class Calibrator
{
public:
    double testFun(const double& arg);
    double doThing();
    
    double x = 9.8;
};

testLib.cpp
#include "testLib.h"
#include "optimize.h"

double Calibrator::testFun(const double& arg)
{
    x *= arg;
    return x;
}

double Calibrator::doThing()
{
    return Optimizer(testFun,
                     10);
}

How can I fix this situation, preferably without completely restructuring the code by doing something wacky like making the optimizer part of the sensor calibration class?

"Old" functions taking a callback with pointer on function should also take void* to pass user data, it is not your case, so yo have to workaround that with some drawback. Setting a global Calibrator*, and applying the  function on that global is a possibility (cannot be called concurrency with different object).

@Jarod42, I'm not sure I 100% follow, could you provide an answer with example code? I'd really appreciate it

"This is a bit tricky to describe" -- Doubtful. Usually, this is a sign that the writer is not thinking abstractly enough and is unnecessarily bogged down in details. For example, you are trying to use a C++ class member function as a C callback function; which other details of your scenario need to be considered?

"preferably without completely restructuring the code by doing something wacky like making the optimizer part of the sensor calibration class?" -- Is this an option? More to the point, are you able to change the source code for one or both libraries? If so, that would open possibilities that are usually off the table when dealing with libraries.

@JaMiT I can change both libraries, but I don't want to have the optimizer library in any way dependent on the sensor library. I'd like to keep the optimizer lib as generic as possible. Do you have any ideas?

Every C-style callback function must have an additional void* parameter. If yours doesn't have one, change it. (This doesn't make your library depend on anything additional). If somebody else's doesn't have one, file a bug report.

@P_B "but I don't want to have the optimizer library in any way dependent on the sensor library." -- That's why I provided the "more to the point" question. ;) -- "Do you have any ideas?" Well, "Common practice is to pass a pointer to 'data' together with the function" as seen in "an example of callbacks in C", although maybe it would be better to start with the question What's void *userData exactly? to understand how libraries often handle your situation.

As you seem to be able to modify library,
Optimizer has to be fixed:

old C compatible way
double Optimizer(double (*func)(void* /*userdata*/, double),
                 void* userdata,
                 double arg)
{
    return func(userdata, arg);
}

and then
double Calibrator::doThing()
{
    return Optimizer(+[](void* calibrator, double d) {
        return static_cast<Calibrator*>(calibrator)->testfunc(d);
    }, this, 10);
}


C++ ways, without type erasure, with template
template <typename F>
requires (std::invocable<F, double>
      && std::is_convertible_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, double>, double>)
double Optimizer(F f, double arg)
{
    return f(arg);
}


or with type erasure with std::function/std::move_only_function/function_ref
double Optimizer(std::function<double>(double) f, double arg)
{
    return f(arg);
}

and, for both of them, then
double Calibrator::doThing()
{
    return Optimizer([this](const double& d) {
        return this->testfunc(d);
    }, 10);
}




Thanks! I'm running this code embedded, so I don't want to use std functions if I don't have to. In the C implementation, what is the "+" in front of the lambda function for? Also, what is the "static_cast" doing?

+ before lambda is to "explicitly" convert into function pointer (would be done implicitly without.

doc of static_cast.
